# How to show external link in TweetVIew(Fabrics Twitter) in Android

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

Need to integrate Twitter tweets in applications. I have Used Fabric(Super easy to integrate). Tweets are coming smoothly. but the externals links are not visible as same as twitter app.[image] [image: MY applications showing tweets like this [![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PGD7.png)

nasa revels juno link is rendering in twitter app but not in In my app. I am using TweetView

Twitter link
https://twitter.com/ZeeNews/status/749101563130421248